# Send Ctrl + C signal to PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, go, exec

I want to start PowerShell, execute a command and be able to terminate it at any time.
I use `exec.Command()` to start PowerShell with a few flags and then the `-command $pid`, I figured I could just open another PowerShell process and use `taskkill /F /PID` to kill the other PowerShell process but for some reason it says it's killed but it still goes on, when I hit `ctrl + C` then it immediately exits.

In my tests I use the `ping -n 50 google.com` command because it takes time. Now my question is how can I send `ctrl + C` signal to that PowerShell process to terminate it mid command execution.

The reason is that if a command gets stuck or takes longer than anticipated you don't have to wait for it.

```
cmd := exec.Command("powershell", "-nologo", "-noexit", "-command", "$pid")

    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    cmd.Start()

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    bytes, _ := stdout.Read(buf)
    pid := string(buf[:bytes])

    log.Println("[+] Shell PID:", cmd.Process.Pid)
    log.Println("[+] Powershell PID:", pid)

    fmt.Fprintln(stdin, "ping -n 50 google.com")
    stdin.Close()

    count := 0
    for {
        n, err := stdout.Read(buf)
        if err == io.EOF {break}
        if err != nil {panic(err)}
        fmt.Print(string(buf[:n]))
        count += 1

        if count >= 15 && count <= 20 {
            log.Println("[-] Powershell killed")
            
            // my attempt at sending ctrl +  C signal
            // It returns error: not supported by windows
            pid_int, err :=strconv.Atoi(pid)
            if err != nil {panic(err)}
            proc, err := os.FindProcess(pid_int)
            if err != nil {panic(err)}
            err = proc.Signal(syscall.Signal(syscall.CTRL_C_EVENT))
            if err != nil {panic(err)}
            
            log.Println("[-] Shell killed")
            cmd.Process.Kill()
        }
    }
```

Comment: An event is not a signal, but I know windows handles all these strangely anyway since it doesn't really have signals. Did you try `os.Interrupt`? (which is `syscall.SIGINT`)

Comment: @JimB Tried it just now, still says it's not supported by windows.

Comment: AFAIK, signals are emulated in Go-on-Windows only when it comes to reacting on them. Pressing Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break are handled directly by the console and are converted into calls to certain callbacks an application hosted by a console can register in it. Go does register them, so it can react to `os.Interrupt` being "sent" by the console to the process even though Windows does not have signals. It does not work in other direction; you should call ExitProcess or TerminateProcess from kernel32.dll.

Comment: Note that both these functions are exported by the stock `syscall` standard package (when compiling for GOOS=windows)

Comment: There is still no Wait call. `go cmd.Wait()` between Start() and the for loop might be enough to make this work. You can also give CommandContext a try.

Comment: @kostix Thank you for the idea, I tried both but the same thing happens. It says it terminates but the windows is still running, then as soon as I hit ctrl + c to stop the ping command the PowerShell windows immediately closes.

Comment: @Peter Thank you so much, I'm pretty sure that's it since I'm getting a `panic: read |0: file already closed` error.

Comment: @Niu, are you sure you're trying to terminate a correct process? TerminateProcess is fatal, the target process cannot somehow handle it and not terminate.

Comment: JFTR, TerminateProcess takes the handle of a process, not its PID; to get that handle given the PID, use OpenProcess (and make sure to call CloseHandle on the handle it returned, in case that succeeded).